# delaying the sending of email messages without using Thread.Sleep c#

Tags: c#

I have a for loop which loops through and sends an email each loop. Right now im using thread.sleep() but I want the user to still be able to interact with the program, just delap that one loop. Is it possible to do this without using thread.sleep?

Comment: Move the loop to a background thread. If the email sending must be on the main/GUI thread, elevate the actual sending to the main thread, but move the sleeping to a background thread.

Comment: Does it need to send an email on each loop iteration? or would it be sufficient to send one (or more) after you complete the loop?

Comment: Not sure why anyone hasn't asked this already but...why exactly are you delaying the send?

Comment: @James, may have many reason. One may be "server does not allow sending too many mails in a short period of time"

Comment: @edokan that sort of thing should really be the job of the mail server, not the client app. This is why I am interested in hearing the reason *why* the delay is required as there may be an underlying design problem here.

Comment: @James, you are absolutely right, but tell that to mail server developers.

Comment: yeah the server im sending the mail too doesnt handle 10 or so emails at once very well. Just now checking this again so ill try these suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the loop on the UI thread?  If so, just use Task.Factory.StartNew to run your loop in a different thread. If you need to delay the email sending at that time, put a Thread.Sleep before you actually begin looping.

It will look something like this:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This code happens on the UI thread
    Task.Factory.StartNew(SendEmails);
}

private void SendEmails()
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    foreach(var email in emailAddresses) {
        SendEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm this method doesnt seem to want to work since im not using a System method to send the emails. Im sending them through outlook using a template email.

Comment: Please tell me more.  I'm not sure why the exact method would change the result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the method of sending mail in separated thread to keep your GUI interactive .

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendMail));
newThread.Start();

public void SendMail() 
{
    //Send mails here       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spin off a new thread to send the emails so you don't lock the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try shifting the code to background Thread.