# starting a new thread and calling a method with arguments C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, email, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delaying the sending of email messages without using Thread.Sleep c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675864/delaying-the-sending-of-email-messages-without-using-thread-sleep-c-sharp)

so i am trying to start a new thread inside a for loop of my application. Im not familiar with threading at all so I need some info.

im sending emails through outlook using this method:

```
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(string recipient, string subject, string body)
    {

        try
        {

            // Create the Outlook application.
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            // Set HTMLBody. 
            //add the body of the email
            oMsg.Body = body;

            oMsg.Subject = subject;
            // Add a recipient.
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
            // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
            oRecip.Resolve();
            // Send.
            oMsg.Send();
            // Clean up.
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
        }//end of try block
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }//end of catch

        //end of Email Method
    }
```

and in a foreach loop i send an email each iteration.

However i need those emails delayed, but I dont want to sleep the UI thread.

I asked a few hours ago and got some answers but wasnt able to check my question frequently.

I tried some of their suggestions such as using this:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart((sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(recipient, subjectLine, finalbody)));
```

But im getting an error. Its saying its expecting a method name...and i do have a method name in there. Is it because of the arguments of my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this or also look into ParameterizedThreadStart:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(recipient, subjectLine, finalbody); }));
```

Comment: but how do i sleep that thread?

Comment: nevermind, got it. just used Thread.sleep in the email method and when the sendemail method is called it sleeps the current (newly created) thread

Comment: nevermind it still isnt sleeping...hmm